# SQL Server : Tracking a slow running query on completion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Am trying to work on script for slow-running queries. I understand that we can get the list of slow running queries using [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx). Say, I have a query Q1 which is running very slow, say, 1 hour. Till Q1 is running i.e. executing, I can track it using sys.dm_exec_requests DMV. If I understood it right, once Q1 is completed, its statistics will be no more available in this DMV. Instead, we need to look at [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx). But how do I get the statistics of that specific query Q1 which had been slow-running ? Meaning how do I relate the data I earlier got in sys.dm_exec_requests and sys.dm_exec_query_stats?

Comment: You've listed three vastly different versions of SQL Server. Does whatever solution need to work on all of them?

Comment: yes @BenThul . We have varied SQL configurations ; hence the need.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're operating across such a broad range of versions, you're going to have to go with the lowest common denominator, which is SQL trace. Set up a trace to stored procedure completes and ad hoc statement completes that take longer than some threshold. Then run it server side and view the output every once in a while.

It bears noting that if 2005 wasn't in the mix, I'd have suggested extended events.